# Laravel 8 – API deploy in live server problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I’m fairly new to Laravel and this post is mostly for learning purposes, so don’t mind the rudimentary approach, architecture and deploy method I’m using here. Also, it’s the first time I attempt to deploy a Laravel project to a live server.

**The problem:**
I’m transcribing a custom CMS that I built from scratch from other languages like .NET/node/react/vanilla PHP into Laravel.

Frontend and Backend share basically the same source files, except for the .env files. Architecture was set up for the frontend to fetch data from the backend API.

- Frontend temporary domain: http://multiplatformphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache4.cloudsector.net/ (local dev: http://localhost:8000)
- Backend temporary domain: http://backendphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache2.cloudsector.net/  (local dev: http://localhost:8001)
  (no need to visit them – just extra information)

Full code base can be found here:
https://github.com/jorge-mauricio/laravel8

Up till now, I did all my development locally and everything worked fine. However, when I deployed my code to the live servers, a very strange behavior is happening:

- The frontend load fine (web routes) – which tells me that the deployment settings are OK;
- The backend APIs seem to return null when I try to fetch them through the frontend. Example:

```php
$apiAuthenticationCheckURL = 'http://backendphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache2.cloudsector.net/api/authentication/';
$apiAuthenticationCheckResponse = Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])
    ->post(
        $apiAuthenticationCheckURL,
        array_merge(
            [
                'verificationType' => 'user_admin',
                'apiKey' => config('app.gSystemConfig.configAPIKeySystem'),
            ],
            $req->all()
        )
    );
$arrAuthenticationCheckJson = $apiAuthenticationCheckResponse->json();
```

GitHub code reference: https://github.com/jorge-mauricio/laravel8/blob/main/syncsystem-laravel8-v1/app/Http/Controllers/AdminLoginController.php#L97-L110

The `$apiAuthenticationCheckResponse` is returning null when I `dd($apiAuthenticationCheckResponse)` in the line after and it should return data. I already debugged `$apiAuthenticationCheckURL` and it’s printing the correct API route.

Now comes the strange part: when I test the API route in my postman (in the same computer that I developed and tested locally all my code) it returns me the expected reponse.
[image: printscreen_postman_live_server_reponse]

And the response is exactly the same as when I use the local dev endpoint (http://localhost:8001)

Another weird behavior is that I can assert that the API’s routes are working fine through this opened API endpoint:
http://backendphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache2.cloudsector.net/api/categories/0
Maybe has to do with some extra configuration related to the `Http::withOptions` method.

So my first guess is that I should enable my frontend server IP or domain somewhere in Laravel but I haven’t got a clue of where it might be.

Also, before anyone point to this, the `TrustedHosts` middleware is still disabled:
https://github.com/jorge-mauricio/laravel8/blob/main/syncsystem-laravel8-v1/app/Http/Kernel.php#L19

**Full context:**

- Laravel 8;
- Original Laravel 8 .htaccess file in both public folders;
- Shared hosting type of accounts, so there’s limitations of command line, etc;
- Servers PHP 8.0.30;
  [image: printscreen_php_version]

**Deploy method:**
Again – very rudimentary until I have a good grasp of what’s going on.

- I created two separate accounts (different IPs) on a shared hosting service;
- I uploaded the files through FTP (including the dependencies) so I did’t run any composer or php artisan command for anything;
- I just edited the public/index.php file to point to the correct import paths and minor differences in the .env files to point to the live production endpoints;

**Sanctum note:**
The project uses sanctum for some of the authentication logic, but I don’t think that’s the problem yet. Anyway, I updated this line to include all my live servers IPs:
https://github.com/jorge-mauricio/laravel8/blob/main/syncsystem-laravel8-v1/config/sanctum.php#L20

```php
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,
    192.96.210.51,192.96.210.51:34512,multiplatformphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache4.cloudsector.net,
    192.96.210.16,backendphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache2.cloudsector.net',
    Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
))),
```

I still think the key here would be with accessing the API endpoint from the computer where I developed the Laravel project (including the artisan commands) versus accessing the API endpoints through the server (frontend).

If there would be a way for me to configure manually something that I should have done through a command line, would be awesome, as I feel I’m really close to resolving this step of the learning process.

Or if someone can tell if there’s a step I’m missing when deploying Laravel projects to live servers, would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit – Progress on debugging and found the root cause:**

I may have found the cause for the problem, but still researching for a solution. After digging in a bit more I found [this article in Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/api-posts-in-production-not-working) and seems that the problem has to do with the trailing slash in the URI.

The URI I’m setting originally looked like: `http://backendphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache2.cloudsector.net/api/authentication/`

If I delete the trailing slash, I’m able to get the data through Http::withOptions: `http://backendphplaravel8v1-syncsystem-com-br.apache2.cloudsector.net/api/authentication`

The problem for debugging was the fact that locally, it worked with the trailing slash (artisan server), so it may be something to do with apache server or the .htaccess in public.

Also, the API route I set has the trailing slash, so I’m not quite sure why is erroring:

```php
Route::post(
    '/authentication/',
    [
        ApiAuthenticationController::class, 'authenticationCheck'
    ],
    function ($authenticationCheckResults) {
        return response()->json($authenticationCheckResults);
    }
)
    ->name(api.authentication);
```

https://github.com/jorge-mauricio/laravel8/blob/main/syncsystem-laravel8-v1/routes/routes-api-authentication.php#L12

I’d like to maintain the trailing slash in the URI build, so what would I need to do in order for it to work as is? Would there be a configuration in Laravel that I can set, or in the API route configuration, or should I handle it in the .htacess file level?

Comment: if `$apiAuthenticationCheckResponse` is null, it sounds to me like the problem is with the server making the request rather than the one responding. Check the laravel logs for any exceptions or apache logs for any errors.